# Hibernate : @ValueGenerationType dentro de un EmbeddedId no funciona al hacer INSERT

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Estoy intentando añadir a mi proyecto (uso Spring 5.0.2, Spring-data-jpa 2.0.5 y Hibernate 5.2.14) una nueva anotación que me permita obtener la fecha directamente de la base de datos (Postgresql) en vez de la VM.

Para ello, he tomado como base el siguiente [articulo](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html#_in_database_generation).

El problema es que el INSERT que Hibernate está intentando hacer en la base de datos y que se muestra por la consola, no incluye current_date en el campo que tocaría, sino que intenta insertar un valor nulo y, al ser una PK y no admitir el valor nulo, salta una excepción de restricción violada.

Resumiendo, parece que no se está invocando la nueva anotación que he creado y con la que decoro el atributo correspondiente, ¿necesito configurar algo más?, ¿tengo que añadir alguna otra anotación previa?

Mi nueva anotación DataBaseDate:

```
@ValueGenerationType(generatedBy = DataBaseDateGenerator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DataBaseDate {

    GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() default GenerationTiming.ALWAYS;

}
```

Mi clase DataBaseDateGenerator:

```
public class DataBaseDateGenerator implements AnnotationValueGeneration<DataBaseDate> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public GenerationTiming getGenerationTiming() {
        return GenerationTiming.ALWAYS;
    }

    @Override
    public ValueGenerator<?> getValueGenerator() {
        // no in-memory generation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean referenceColumnInSql() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseGeneratedReferencedColumnValue() {
        return "current_date";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(final DataBaseDate annotation, final Class<?> propertyType) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

La clase que define el id Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
public class ComplexJPAPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id_anuncio", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idAnuncio;

    @Column(name = "fecha_alta", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @DataBaseDate(getGenerationTiming = GenerationTiming.INSERT)
    private LocalDate fechaAlta;

    public ComplexJPAPK() {
        super();
    }

    // getters/setters omitidos para simplificar la lectura

}
```

La clase que define el EmbeddedId:

```
@Entity
public class ComplexJPA  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ComplexJPAPK id;

    private String codArticulo = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    public ComplexJPA() {
        super();
    }

    // getters/setters omitidos para simplificar la lectura
}
```

La clase que contiene a ComplexJPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="anuncio")
public class AnuncioJPA  {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "anuncio", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private final List<ComplexJPA> complexJPAList= new ArrayList<>();

    // Resto de elementos omitidos para simplificar la lectura

    public AnuncioJPA() {
        super();
    }
}
```

El código SQL que se muestra por consola al intentar "salvar" el objeto y donde pre-supongo debería mostrarse la función **current_date** en lugar de esperar un parámetro:

```
Hibernate: insert into complexJPA(responsable, fecha_alta, anuncio_anuncio_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

En cualquier caso, he omitido el código para añadir el elemento ComplexJPA a la clase AnuncioJPA y la llamada a saveAndFlush() de su repositorio, pues si inicializo la fecha (con LocalDate.now()), funciona correctamente, por lo que asumo que el problema no viene de ahí.